# CTRL down and filter don't work for all rows

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel file I use, I have 2 problems that seem related:

1. Filter stops working after row 1338, after that, content is not filtered. No matter what is inside a cell, it will not be affected by the filter past row 1338. The column I'm trying to use to filter contains company names in the form of text.
2. CTRL down brings the Active cell to row 1338 even though it is not the last cell with content.

I tried removing the filters and reapplying them. I have tried setting the Scroll Area past row 1338. Nothing worked.

I have no hidden rows.

Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Would need futher Information on how you are filtering. For example a number may be displayed as a 21 but is actually a 21.000001

Comment: Any hidden rows?

Comment: I added precisions to my questions, thanks for the comments!

Comment: Have you got an official table on the sheet down to row 1338, and then a continuation below it that just ***looks*** like the rest of the table due to formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds from your description as though you have a Table, which currently runs down as far as row 1,338 - and then more data below that has been added but not auto detected by Excel as extra rows so is treated as separate data.

Click on a cell in the uppermost 1,338 rows and hopefully you'll see a DESIGN tab appear in your Excel ribbon.

[image: DesignTab]

Select it and then on the far left side you should see an option to RESIZE TABLE.
[image: ResizeTable screengrab]

Alter the range in the box to cover your entire data and this should fix the problem.
[image: ResizeTable capture screengrab]

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I resized it in a macro. Thanks!